# Extraneous vertical scroll bar in review task header

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, user-interface

There's a vertical scroll bar that's not much use in the header for the review task screens (e.g. [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review-beta/first-posts)). It lets you scroll down one line, but there's nothing to see below.

- Firefox 10

[image: Firefox 10]

- Chromium 22:

[image]

Could this tiny buglet be squashed?

<sub>* Glitch possibly introduced with the **super-awesome** badge progress indicator.

* Doesn't appear on any other site where I have access to review tasks.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next production build.